# Illegal Date strings in Java

Tags: java, datetime

How do I get a DateFormat of some sort to throw an exception if I try to parse an illegal date? If I parse a date like "99.99.9999" with a SimpleDateFormat with the pattern "dd.MM.yyyy", no exception is thrown, but this is clearly not a valid date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`DateFormat.setLenient(false)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))